# I need to compare on linux/bash 2 strings : one exact and one with questions marks posing as filter (like any value is ok)

Tags: linux, bash, compare

Here is an example test case :

(this is the golden template to compare to:)

```
line0 : "test run ok - result is ????% - completed with success"
```

(this is what what could happen)

```
line1 : "test run ok - result is 12.7% - completed with success" 
line2 : "test run ok - result is 13.4% - completed with success"
line3 : "test run not ok - result is disatrous - kill yourself"
```

i need the compare to return :

```
compare(line0, line1) ==> ok
compare(line0, line2) ==> ok
compare(line0, line3) ==> not ok
```

note : the ?? could be place anywhere in the line0 and the comparison need to ignore them in line0 and accordingly (byte sensitive) in line1,2,3

Does anyone have a magic line in bash/linux with a complex or not so complex sed / awk / ... to do so ?
thanks

Comment: `grep "test run ok - result is ....% - completed with success" <<< $line1`, use `.` (period) instead of `?`

Comment: why not grep "success"  and grep -v "success"

Comment: Yesterday i was dumb (and tired), now i am found!  yes yes yes i'll try the {grep} with {.} filter. thanks Timur

Comment: update : the period "."  is a regex filtering thing, so are [ ^ and others, how may I keep only the "." filtering and have the [ ^ and others be processed as normal characters not regex characters ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Conveniently, your template is a simple shell glob. So:

```
compare(){
    case "$2" in
        $1) echo ok ;;
        *) echo not ok ;;
    esac
}

line0="test run ok - result is ????% - completed with success"
line1="test run ok - result is 12.7% - completed with success" 
line2="test run ok - result is 13.4% - completed with success"
line3="test run not ok - result is disatrous - kill yourself"

compare "$line0" "$line1"
compare "$line0" "$line2"
compare "$line0" "$line3"
```